# How to get the URL fragment identifier from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, fragment-identifier

How do I get the URL fragment identifier from `HttpServletRequest`?

The [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) doesn't seem to mention it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't get the URL fragment in the way you'd like.

Typically, the browser doesn't send the fragment to the server. This can be verified by using a network protocol analyser like tcpdump, [Ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/), [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

However, you can send the fragment string as a GET/POST parameter on a JavaScript request. To get the value using JavaScript, use `window.location.hash`. You can then pass this value as a GET or POST parameter in an AJAX request, and use the getParameter methods on the HttpServletRequest for the AJAX request.

Here's what [RFC3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5) has to say:

> The fragment identifier is separated
> from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the
> identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced
> solely by the user agent, regardless of the URI scheme.  Although
> this separate handling is often perceived to be a loss of
> information, particularly for accurate redirection of references as
> resources move over time, it also serves to prevent information
> providers from denying reference authors the right to refer to
> information within a resource selectively.  Indirect referencing also
> provides additional flexibility and extensibility to systems that use
> URIs, as new media types are easier to define and deploy than new
> schemes of identification.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the following link: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396

Comment: How could it help with *getting* the fragment from http request?