# How do #hashes work in URL schemes if they're not part of URL request?

Tags: url, browser, hashtag

I'm trying to figure out how the browsers handle the hashes in the url requests and the page rendering.

For example, let's say I go to `www.example.com/#footer`.

When I request this URL the browser makes the `GET` request to the `www.example.com` but doesn't have the `#footer` in the request.

When the page loads, the browser knows I asked for the `#footer` and jumps to that location.

What happens in the more complex situations when I do a redirect? For example, let's say I `301` redirect to `www.example.com/birds/#middle`. How does the browser know that it can jump to the `#middle` if hash is not part of the request URL?

Also how does web server know that I'm about to jump to particular anchor `#hash` so that it can serve content just for `#hash`? (Like facebook does when you go from one section to another. Only `#hash` anchor tag changes.)

Answer (score 2):

They called anchors [here is definition and examples](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3). Once the page loaded the browser is looking for this "anchor" and moves page there if it finds it.

Comment: Thanks. I thought they were called #hashtags. I'll read your blog page that you linked to.

Comment: Thanks for edit. How does web server know that the browser will move to particular anchor though? Anchor hash tag is not part of request as far as I know?

Comment: Browser knows because it is part of a w3c standard and ancor is part of the link (or Get request for that matter).

Comment: As far as I know Get request doesnt include anchor? Get request only include URL up to hash. Browser somehow maintains #hash state separately from server. Can you confirm or deny?

Comment: Well, it appears that anchors or as also refered Fragment identifiers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) according to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator are part of URL. So they are part of the link and browser knows it when you clik. This question answers how server might know about fragemnt ids http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503213/how-to-get-the-url-fragment-identifier-from-httpservletrequest the fact that they are not part of Get itself is interesting, didn't know befere stated to look.