# How to access the hash value from URL inside controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-boot

Here is the URL and I wanted to read the value post **hash**. I did't find a direct way to get the hash value so looking for a indirect way, If I could read the full URL with hash somehow, I can easily parse.

```
http://localhost:8080/igcallback#access_token=<token>
```

**What I Tried**

String access_token = request.getRequestURL()

```
http://localhost:8080/igcallback
```

String request_param= request.getParameter("access_token");

```
null
```

String header_names = request.getHeaderNames()

```
[]
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470421/pathvariable-in-springboot-with-slashes-in-url/43471437#43471437

Comment: That was my question. I have tested this situation with # - all after hash is ignored.

Comment: did it happen for you to get a solution finally? though it's pretty easy to handle this in JavaScript side.

Comment: Now I don't know the solution. However I don't need this for my case. I set some simple rules for my users so that I can handle their input well.

Comment: But If you have Javascript web-client can you get necessary information from URL by JS and only then call your server with proper params?

Comment: It's web service and don't have java script, fully server side. I said it would be straight forward in javascript but not in java

Answer (score 1):

The fragment hash is not sent to the server in most cases, so you can't really.

See this answer for reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13503246/685876

Comment: it's a work around using Javascript. my code does'n user JS as it's a rest based web service.