# How to send a URL Fragment(#) from a controller to a view in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to send a url like this (below)
`http://localhost:8080/adminProjectsViewAll#projectDetailsModal`

but how to send it from a Spring Boot Controller

My `application.properties` :

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test3
spring.datasource.username=user1
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

#server.servlet.context-path=/ems
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the URL fragment identifier from HttpServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503213/how-to-get-the-url-fragment-identifier-from-httpservletrequest)

Comment: No I have to Send It from controller to the View @xerx593